# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined y GET 403 en aplicación angular

Tags: nodejs, angular, api, heroku, mapbox

estoy usando la api de openweather y mapBox en angular 10. Estos errores que tengo saltan también en desarrollo así como en heroku, el link es este:https://wheater-app-amichetti.herokuapp.com/

Estoy teniendo este problema que antes no tenía.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at scripts.828ac566223a5fc911a1.js:1
```

y al completar los campos de país y ciudad tira el siguiente error:

```
GET https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Rosario,argentina&appid=1a672f6d7425ab40084bb8c4a53d8c53 403 (Forbidden)
```

El server.js es este:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();


// Serve only the static files form the angularapp directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/angularapp'));

app.get('/*', function(req,res) {

res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/angularapp/index.html'));
});

// Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Si necesitan algún código más me avisan. Tuve errores de todo tipo y al resolverlos saltaban otros que antes parecían escondidos o funcionaban. Estoy medio perdido.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: El error 403 significa que no tienes acceso a la API a la que le haces el GET, deberías conseguir un token de acceso o alguna forma de autenticación. Con respecto al otro error, estas mostrando un log de consola de un código en produccion al parecer y asi es casi imposible ayudarte. Deberias correr tu aplicación en modo debugger para ver en detalle el error

Comment: El token de acceso lo tengo. En desarrollo me da los mismos errores por eso no los agregué. Lo raro es que antes no me psaba y funcionaba todo ok en desarrollo, no así en producción.